# Building a custom DNN eCommerce Mega Menu and bringing back Product Categories from a separate ERP database and linking the two

Tags: menu, e-commerce, dotnetnuke

I need to build an eCommerce Mega Menu which should build the menu items as normal in DNN.

I would need to bring back an Object from our own custom ERP system which contains product categories.

These categories contain Parent and Children Categories.

I can't use an existing Shopping Module as our company works differently and has developed all the other required modules for a shopping system.

I have looked at this tutorial using DDR Menu's: https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/140362/advanced-menu-design-with-ddrmenu

If I download [this folder](https://github.com/jbrinkman/TopMenu/zipball/master) on the above-mentioned website, how do I change the skin objects to use this and where do I place these files in the website root?

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

I have also looked at a folder in the Skins folder containing code that builds the current menu:

[image]

I noticed that the ULTokens.txt file contains the structure of how a menu is built, how would I be able to add one link of our own from our ERP system in a DNN module and inject our Object with the Product Categories?

ULTokens.txt code:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The comments I made in your other post apply.

For the case where you are trying to build the menu to include data from an external store, you'll probably want to use a razor template for your menu.  Then, you can include code to grab the external data to add to your menu template.

The razor version of the mega-menu template may give you some starting pointers.